# Checkout Git files to a location outside the repository

Tags: git, checkout

Is it possible to “checkout” to a location outside of the repository? What I mean is a clone of a branch without the “.git” directory.

For example: Use git to manage a website. You edit some files, commit and copy the files to a web server via WebDAV. The WebDAV-path would be the location outside the repository, which shouldn't contain the “.git”.

This may not be the problem for which git was build, but is this possible?

Comment: You can also use `git show` to check out files to any path you want, as this answer shows here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888414/git-checkout-older-revision-of-a-file-under-a-new-name/888623#888623.

Answer (score 21):

Yes, this is certainly possible.

Lets say I have a bare repository named `/srv/production.git` on the destination system/server.

On the destination system I can use the command `cd /srv/production.git; GIT_WORK_TREE=/srv/production-www/ git checkout -f`

If I am in a non-bare repository the command is slightly different.  Lets say I have a non-bare respository at `/srv/testing`.  To checkout that I would use `cd /srv/testing/.git; GIT_WORK_TREE=/srv/production-www/ git checkout -f`

In fact on my system I even automate this in a post-commit hook in my `production.git` repository.  So when you push to `production.git` the latest version is automatically check out to the web root.

```bash
#!/bin/sh
#
# An example hook script that is called after a successful
# commit is made.
#
# To enable this hook, rename this file to "post-commit".

GIT_WORK_TREE=/srv/production-www/ git checkout -f
# ... misc other commands to verify permissions are set correctly.
```

If your only access to the remote system is webdav, it certainly should be possible to write a post-commit hook that will checkout to the webdav host, either directly or to a temporary location, which you can then script an upload.

Comment: searched in multiple places.. only working solution, also clean!

Answer (score 7):

If you just want the files, you can use [`git archive`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-archive.html). Usually it writes to an archive like tarballs or ZIP, but you can pipe it as well:

```
git archive master | tar -x -C /some/path
```

Here, `master` obviously is the branch you want to archive, and `/some/path` will contain just the files – no `.git` or `.gitignore`.

---

Or you can use [`git checkout-index`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout-index.html) which more closely resembles a "checkout" of files:

```
git checkout-index -f -a --prefix=/some/path/
```

Here, the `-a` option tells `git` to check out all files. The prefix will be prepended to the output. Somebody also wrote [a wrapper around this](https://github.com/dasch/git-export/blob/master/git-export) to give a `git export`.

Comment: I think you are making this more difficult than it needs to be.  Just run `GIT_WORK_TREE=/destinationpath git checkout -f` while your current directory is at the top of a bare repository, or the .git subdirectory.  You will get a checkout to /destinationpath

Comment: Ok, I must have somehow missed that option, +1 to you.

Comment: I find this option way more intuitive, to be honest. And less error prone.

Answer (score 3):

Since Git **[1.8.5](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git/1.8.5#git--Cltpathgt)**, you can use **`-C <path>`** option, to run as if git was started in `<path>`, instead of the current working directory.

On **older Git** versions, use **`--work-tree`** option. For example::

```
repo_url=https://github.com/owner/project.git
repo_dir=$(basename $repo_url .git)
git clone $repo_url
git --work-tree=$repo_dir checkout $branch
```