# git export part of bare repository?

Tags: git, checkout

I'd like to perform a *partial* "export" (only one subdirectory) of a bare repo. I've tried some solutions in the answers to [Checkout Git files to a location outside the repository](https://superuser.com/q/624259/319302), however none seemed to work on a bare repo (`operation must be run in a work tree`).

Is this even possible?

Comment: Why do you need partial export from bare repository? Bare repository is for sharing not for working.

Comment: @Nikolai I was thinking I'd use a bare repository on a server with a push-to-deploy system, but certain files need to be placed in different places. Perhaps there's a better way to do this?

Comment: Try to read the following pages:

Comment: http://www.infoworld.com/article/2909346/application-development/improving-on-git-flow-for-continuous-delivery.html

Comment: http://blogs.atlassian.com/2014/04/practical-continuous-deployment/

Comment: http://www.slideshare.net/bmchild/git-in-continuous-deployment